# Phoenix Channel - Erlang KeyError when connecting

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm following through the Programming Phoenix book and am running in to a server error when trying to connect to an authenticated channel.  The error is:

`[error] Process #PID<0.1000.0> raised an exception
** (ErlangError) erlang error: [reason: %KeyError{key: :user_id, term: %{current_user: %Rumbl.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>, annotations: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :annotations is not loaded>, id: 6, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2015-12-14T17:57:37Z>, name: "Joe", password: nil, password_hash: "$2b$12$TkUgAyJvSroft6KNhs8ECukFkrREZ/jS2xZUTLdp3oQuV.px22WrS", updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2015-12-14T17:57:37Z>, username: "joe", videos: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :videos is not loaded>}}}, mfa: {Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket, :init, 3}, stacktrace: [{Rumbl.UserSocket, :id, 1, [file: 'web/channels/user_socket.ex', line: 46]}, {Phoenix.Socket.Transport, :connect_vsn, 6, [file: 'lib/phoenix/socket/transport.ex', line: 154]}, {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, :init, 2, [file: 'lib/phoenix/transports/websocket.ex', line: 73]}, {Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket, :init, 3, [file: 'lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy_websocket.ex', line: 11]}, {:cowboy_handler, :handler_init, 4, [file: 'src/cowboy_handler.erl', line: 64]}, {:cowboy_protocol, :execute, 4, [file: 'src/cowboy_protocol.erl', line: 442]}], req: [socket: #Port<0.60203>, transport: :ranch_tcp, connection: :keepalive, pid: #PID<0.1000.0>, method: "GET", version: :"HTTP/1.1", peer: {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 49668}, host: "localhost", host_info: :undefined, port: 4000, path: "/socket/websocket", path_info: :undefined, qs: "token=g3QAAAACZAAEZGF0YWEGZAAGc2lnbmVkbgYA57J57lEB--NwLr3U3AgY8nAsNdr7Uya86zUrE%3D&vsn=1.0.0", qs_vals: :undefined, bindings: [], headers: [{"host", "localhost:4000"}, {"connection", "Upgrade"}, {"pragma", "no-cache"}, {"cache-control", "no-cache"}, {"upgrade", "websocket"}, {"origin", "http://localhost:4000"}, {"sec-websocket-version", "13"}, {"user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"}, {"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch"}, {"accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.8"}, {"cookie", "SnapABugHistory=1#; _ga=GA1.1.577046204.1438865191; access_token=f4070d3a1906ebff569d311aa0ddd842c8ef30ee; user-hash=d569532a977f78e1d96d5bab3412a265; SnapABugVisit=86#1449075542; _rumbl_key=g3QAAAACbQAAAAtfY3NyZl90b2tlbm0AAAAYRUoxM1A2NnNNelRoSkR1TGxjaWM2UT09bQAAAAd1c2VyX2lkYQY=--P7j+4zmpEx4KRG4Eq5xZXruIM0Y="}, {"sec-websocket-key", "XjCnurWNHP47g1gcmQN5LA=="}, {"sec-websocket-extensions", "permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits"}], p_headers: [{"connection", ["upgrade"]}], cookies: :undefined, meta: [], body_state: :waiting, buffer: "", multipart: :undefined, resp_compress: false, resp_state: :waiting, resp_headers: [], resp_body: "", onresponse: :undefined], opts: {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, {Rumbl.Endpoint, Rumbl.UserSocket, :websocket}}]
    (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
[error] Ranch protocol #PID<0.1000.0> (:cowboy_protocol) of listener Rumbl.Endpoint.HTTP terminated
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ErlangError) erlang error: [reason: %KeyError{key: :user_id, term: %{current_user: %Rumbl.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>, annotations: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :annotations is not loaded>, id: 6, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2015-12-14T17:57:37Z>, name: "Joe", password: nil, password_hash: "$2b$12$TkUgAyJvSroft6KNhs8ECukFkrREZ/jS2xZUTLdp3oQuV.px22WrS", updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2015-12-14T17:57:37Z>, username: "joe", videos: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :videos is not loaded>}}}, mfa: {Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket, :init, 3}, stacktrace: [{Rumbl.UserSocket, :id, 1, [file: 'web/channels/user_socket.ex', line: 46]}, {Phoenix.Socket.Transport, :connect_vsn, 6, [file: 'lib/phoenix/socket/transport.ex', line: 154]}, {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, :init, 2, [file: 'lib/phoenix/transports/websocket.ex', line: 73]}, {Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket, :init, 3, [file: 'lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy_websocket.ex', line: 11]}, {:cowboy_handler, :handler_init, 4, [file: 'src/cowboy_handler.erl', line: 64]}, {:cowboy_protocol, :execute, 4, [file: 'src/cowboy_protocol.erl', line: 442]}], req: [socket: #Port<0.60203>, transport: :ranch_tcp, connection: :keepalive, pid: #PID<0.1000.0>, method: "GET", version: :"HTTP/1.1", peer: {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 49668}, host: "localhost", host_info: :undefined, port: 4000, path: "/socket/websocket", path_info: :undefined, qs: "token=g3QAAAACZAAEZGF0YWEGZAAGc2lnbmVkbgYA57J57lEB--NwLr3U3AgY8nAsNdr7Uya86zUrE%3D&vsn=1.0.0", qs_vals: :undefined, bindings: [], headers: [{"host", "localhost:4000"}, {"connection", "Upgrade"}, {"pragma", "no-cache"}, {"cache-control", "no-cache"}, {"upgrade", "websocket"}, {"origin", "http://localhost:4000"}, {"sec-websocket-version", "13"}, {"user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"}, {"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch"}, {"accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.8"}, {"cookie", "SnapABugHistory=1#; _ga=GA1.1.577046204.1438865191; access_token=f4070d3a1906ebff569d311aa0ddd842c8ef30ee; user-hash=d569532a977f78e1d96d5bab3412a265; SnapABugVisit=86#1449075542; _rumbl_key=g3QAAAACbQAAAAtfY3NyZl90b2tlbm0AAAAYRUoxM1A2NnNNelRoSkR1TGxjaWM2UT09bQAAAAd1c2VyX2lkYQY=--P7j+4zmpEx4KRG4Eq5xZXruIM0Y="}, {"sec-websocket-key", "XjCnurWNHP47g1gcmQN5LA=="}, {"sec-websocket-extensions", "permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits"}], p_headers: [{"connection", ["upgrade"]}], cookies: :undefined, meta: [], body_state: :waiting, buffer: "", multipart: :undefined, resp_compress: false, resp_state: :waiting, resp_headers: [], resp_body: "", onresponse: :undefined], opts: {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, {Rumbl.Endpoint, Rumbl.UserSocket, :websocket}}]
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4`

line 46 of user_socket.ex is:

```
def id(socket), do: "users_socket:#{socket.assigns.user_id}"
```

What am I missing here?  Thanks!

Comment: Ouch, this error message does not look friendly at all. Can you please tell me your Phoenix and Elixir versions?

Comment: @JoséValim, the answer below answered my question.  Unfortunately, I have upgrade to the latest elixir and phoenix, so I don't remember which exact versions produced this error.  I think it was elixir 1.1 and phoenix 1.0.

Comment: No worries, I was able to fix this anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported as an Erratum [here](https://pragprog.com/titles/phoenix/errata) so I am sure it will get fixed in the final revision of the book. To fix the issue, change:

`def id(socket), do: "users_socket:#{socket.assigns.user_id}"`

to:

`def id(socket), do: "users_socket:#{socket.assigns.current_user.id}"`

**Why are you getting this error**

In the `UserSocket` `connect/2`, if a user is authenticated, you are assigning the `current_user` to the `user` in the socket and not the `user_id`:

`{:ok, assign(socket, :current_user, user)}`

So the `socket` does not have a `user_id` key. The `KeyError` error is raised when you call a key that does not exist in a map:

[image]